# The Compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

im trying to show different navigations depend on my data. But im getting this "The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions" error . I know it basically says divide your code but I couldn't find any solution for my project. Anyone have any idea about this problem ?

```
var body: some View {
        
        ZStack{
            
            NavigationView{
                
                ScrollView{
                    
                    LazyVStack{
                        
                        ForEach(storeArray,id:\.id) { item in
                            
                            if item.type == StoreItemType.store_Index.rawValue {
                                
                            NavigationLink(destination:Text("STORE AÇILACAK") ) {
                                
                                Image(uiImage: (item.banner?.url)!.load())
                                    .resizable()
                                    .aspectRatio(CGFloat((item.banner?.ratio)!), contentMode: .fit)
                                    .cornerRadius(12)
                                    .shadow(radius: 4)
                                    .frame(width: CGFloat(UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.9), height: CGFloat((UIScreen.main.bounds.width / CGFloat((item.banner?.ratio) ?? 1))))
                                    
                                    

                            }
                            } else if item.type == StoreItemType.store_link.rawValue {
                                
                                switch item.data?.type {
                                
                                case StoreDataType.html_Content.rawValue:
                                    
                                    NavigationLink(destination:Text("WebView Açılacak") ) {
                                        
                                        Image(uiImage: (item.banner?.url)!.load())
                                            .resizable()
                                            .aspectRatio(CGFloat((item.banner?.ratio)!), contentMode: .fit)
                                            .cornerRadius(12)
                                            .shadow(radius: 4)
                                            .frame(width: CGFloat(UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.9), height: CGFloat((UIScreen.main.bounds.width / CGFloat((item.banner?.ratio) ?? 1))))
                                        
                                            

                                    }

                                case StoreDataType.product_List.rawValue:
                                    
                                    NavigationLink(destination:Text("Ürün Liste Açılacak") ) {
                                        
                                        Image(uiImage: (item.banner?.url)!.load())
                                            .resizable()
                                            .aspectRatio(CGFloat((item.banner?.ratio)!), contentMode: .fit)
                                            .cornerRadius(12)
                                            .shadow(radius: 4)
                                            .frame(width: CGFloat(UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.9), height: CGFloat((UIScreen.main.bounds.width / CGFloat((item.banner?.ratio) ?? 1))))
                                        
                                    }
                                    
                                case StoreDataType.product_Detail.rawValue:
                                    
                                    NavigationLink(destination:Text("Ürün Detay açılacak") ) {
                                        
                                        Image(uiImage: (item.banner?.url)!.load())
                                            .resizable()
                                            .aspectRatio(CGFloat((item.banner?.ratio)!), contentMode: .fit)
                                            .cornerRadius(12)
                                            .shadow(radius: 4)
                                            .frame(width: CGFloat(UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.9), height: CGFloat((UIScreen.main.bounds.width / CGFloat((item.banner?.ratio) ?? 1))))
                                        
                                    }
                                default:
                                    
                                    print("Something Happened")
                                }
                            
                            }
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("United Apps"))
                
            }
            .onAppear {
                
                if isOpened != true {
                    
                    getStoreResponse()
                    
                }
                
            }
            
            ActivityIndicator(isAnimating: $isAnimating)
            
        }
    }
    
    func getStoreResponse() {
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            
            store.storeResponse.sink { (storeResponse) in
                
                isAnimating = false
                
                storeArray.append(contentsOf: storeResponse.items!)
                
                isOpened = true
                
            }.store(in: &cancellable)
            
            store.getStoreResponse()
            
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: As soon as you see such error start breaking your huge view on smaller subviews... and it is good practice to do that from beginning - if your view is longer than couple of dozens of lines - separate it.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you have a common navigation view so first create one struct for navigation view and pass requirement data to a struct. and in the main content view just call this struct. By this, you can break your code and easily maintain your view file and find missing parts and issues.

Code snippet:
Navigation struct

```
struct NavigationImageView: View {
    
    var item: YourItemType
    var destinationText: String
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination:Text(destinationText) ) {
            
            Image(uiImage: (item.banner?.url)!.load())
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(CGFloat((item.banner?.ratio)!), contentMode: .fit)
                .cornerRadius(12)
                .shadow(radius: 4)
                .frame(width: CGFloat(UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.9), height: CGFloat((UIScreen.main.bounds.width / CGFloat((item.banner?.ratio) ?? 1))))
            
        }
    }
}
```

Your main content view

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            NavigationView{
                ScrollView{
                    LazyVStack{
                        ForEach([],id:\.self) { item in
                            
                            if item.type == StoreItemType.store_Index.rawValue {
                                NavigationImageView(item: item, destinationText: "STORE AÇILACAK")
                                
                            } else if item.type == StoreItemType.store_link.rawValue {
                                
                                switch item.data?.type {
                                
                                case StoreDataType.html_Content.rawValue:
                                    NavigationImageView(item: item, destinationText: "WebView Açılacak")
                                
                                    
                                case StoreDataType.product_List.rawValue:
                                    NavigationImageView(item: item, destinationText: "Ürün Liste Açılacak")
                             
                                    /*----------------------------------------
                                     Other case and end code here
                                    /*----------------------------------------
```